# How can I gzip standard in to a file and also print standard in to standard out?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tee

I want to execute a command, have the output of that command get gzip'd on the fly, and also echo/tee out the output of that command.

i.e., something like:

```
echo "hey hey, we're the monkees" | gzip --stdout > my_log.gz
```

Except when the line executes, I want to see this on standard out:

```
hey hey, we're the monkees
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
echo "hey hey, we're the monkees" | tee /dev/tty | gzip --stdout > my_log.gz
```

As pointed out in the comments, `/dev/stdout` might work better than `/dev/tty` in some circumstances.

Comment: What's /dev/tty doing there? The original question wanted the output on standard output, not necessarily on the terminal.

Comment: /dev/tty is a synonym for the current terminal.  The questioner used "standard out" in the customary manner to mean the the current terminal, rather than a more strict definition of the term.

Comment: If it were indeed customary to use "standard output" to mean "current terminal", then that would be a custom likely to lead to much confusion! For this question, bash has /dev/stdout.

Comment: Under what circumstances would /dev/tty not produce the desired outcome where /dev/stdout would?

Comment: When stdout goes to a file and not to the terminal.

Comment: This is just plain not what was asked -- what was asked for was a shell pipeline that would send the output to its `stdout` AND gzip it to a file. (What if I wanted to send the output on to yet another program -- say, **less(1)**.

Comment: /dev/stdout didn't work on Solaris 10 using KSH, but /dev/tty did.

Comment: /dev/stdout will not work in any cases as it is applied after the |.

Comment: @GarethRees you are right but practicality beats purity if you python -m this. you could serve the public with pointing it out in an answer - as opposed to editing the question, which latter would hide the fact that the customary is, arguably, commonplace.

Answer (score 66):

Another way (assuming a shell like `bash` or `zsh`):

```
echo "hey hey, we're the monkees" | tee >(gzip --stdout > my_log.gz)
```

The admittedly strange `>()` syntax basically does the following:

- Create new FIFO (usually something in `/tmp/`)
- Execute command inside `()` and bind the FIFO to stdin on that subcommand
- Return FIFO filename to command line.

What `tee` ends up seeing, then, is something like:

```
tee /tmp/arjhaiX4
```

All `gzip` sees is its standard input.

For Bash, see [`man bash`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) for details. It's in the section on [redirection](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections). For Zsh, see [`man zshexpn`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/zshexpn/) under the heading "Process Substitution."

As far as I can tell, the Korn Shell, variants of the classic Bourne Shell (including ash and dash), and the C Shell don't support this syntax.

Comment: Cool, I'm learning something myself here. Can you elaborate on what is happening there?

Comment: if I read it right, instead of given a file to tee, you've got it sending the copy as input to bracketed expression which writes the gzip output to another file. The uncompressed data leaves tee as normal on stdout

Comment: thanks for the edit, appreciate the extra info! Never knew about that FIFO syntax.

Comment: It came as a shock to me when I first learned it. But it lets you get away with very complex redirections, with several programs operating on the same input simultaneously. Of course, you can also do `mkfifo` by hand and run all of these commands in different consoles if you need to.

Comment: I've been doing Unix for 20 years, and I haven't wrapped my head around this new syntax yet.

Comment: I'm using this for logging. I've found gzip buffers a lot and when I ctrl-c I lose everything. [Ignoring SIGINT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47693330/1888983) with `>(trap '' INT; gzip --stdout > my_log.gz)` seems to save it.

Comment: @jozxyqk Nice! Indeed it seems that gzip buffers [16KB](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/643084/8848) of compressed data before writing

Answer (score 20):

Have a nice cup of [tee](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tee-invocation.html)!

> The tee command copies standard input
>   to standard output and also to any
>   files given as arguments. This is
>   useful when you want not only to send
>   some data down a pipe, but also to
>   save a copy

As I'm having a slow afternoon, here's some gloriously illustrative ascii-art...

```
           +-----+                   +---+                  +-----+  
stdin ->   |cmd 1|    -> stdout ->   |tee|   ->  stdout  -> |cmd 2|
           +-----+                   +---+                  +-----+
                                       |
                                       v
                                     file
```

As greyfade demonstrates in another answer the 'file' need not be a regular file, but could be FIFO letting you pipe that tee'd output into a third command.

```
           +-----+                   +---+                  +-----+  
stdin ->   |cmd 1|    -> stdout ->   |tee|   ->  stdout  -> |cmd 2|
           +-----+                   +---+                  +-----+
                                       |
                                       v
                                     FIFO
                                       |
                                       v
                                    +-----+
                                    |cmd 3|
                                    +-----+
```

Comment: But I want to gzip the intermediary file on the fly.  Is that possible only using tee?

Comment: yes, the other paul wrote a nice succinct answer while I messed about with an ascii art diagram :)

Comment: :-P
I'm familiar with tee'ing to a file like you're describing.  I just don't know how to gzip that file.  if i do "echo foo | tee bar.log", I don't know how to make tee gzip 'bar.log', aside from the solution Paul Tomblin posted.

Comment: man, stackoverflow is awesome.  I didn't even have to harass the office linux guru.
Thanks all.

Comment: greyfade's excellent answer shows how you can do what you like with the tee'd output.

Comment: Yes, grayfade's answer does precisely what this one suggests, but with a very succinct syntax. This ones `cmd 3` is written `>(cmd 3)` there.

Answer (score 6):

Just to post a way that doesn't involve touching disk:

```
echo "hey hey, we're the monkees" | (exec 1>&3 && tee /proc/self/fd/3 | gzip --stdout > my_log.gz)
```

Comment: What, you mean /tmp is on a disk ?!?!?!?

Comment: From a security perspective, it is.