# In bash kill only first process in a pipeline

Tags: linux, bash

If I have a long-running command that periodically outputs some data, e.g. `tail -F` that I want to process with awk (or something else):

```
tail -F service.log | awk '{ ... } END { print ... }'
```

How to kill the first process only (tail in this case) so that I could see the result of `END {}` block in awk? if I press <kbd>Control+C</kbd> the whole pipeline is stopped.

One way I've found to be working is to open a separate tab/window of term, grep PID of the first process and `kill` it from there, but it seems rather clumsy, is there another solution?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
tail -F service.log | (trap '' INT; awk '{ ... } END { print ...}')
```

Comment: You can still kill it with a SIGHUP or in the worst case with SIGKILL. In this limited scenario it will terminate when it gets an EOF from the pipe, anyway.